# django-crispy-forms - Insertando campos en un template

Tags: django, django-forms, bootstrap-3

Tengo el siguiente formulario:

```
class RehabilitationSessionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(RehabilitationSessionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', u'Guardar'))

    class Meta:
        model = RehabilitationSession

        widgets = {
            'pain_extremity':forms.RadioSelect,
            'upper_extremity':forms.RadioSelect,

        }

        fields = ['patient', 'medical', 'therapist', 'date_session_begin',
                  'upper_extremity', 'pain_extremity','movement_up','movement_down',
                  'movement_left','movement_right',
                  'games','game_levels','iterations','game_observations','patient_behavior',
                  'observations','period','date_session_end', ]
```

Deseo poder renderizar todos estos campos en mi template html, de forma separada, es decir ubicar cada campo en `html divs` específicos.

Estoy trabajando con [django-crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) y bootstrap-3

Por el momento, yo estoy renderizando los campos de una forma separada, usando la etiqueta `{{ form.<nombre-del-campo> }}` es decir renderizando los campos [de forma manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) de esta forma:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 pacient-pic">&nbsp &nbsp<img class="img-circle " src="{{ sessionedit.patient.user.photo.url }}" alt="User Avatar">  </div> 
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <ul class="pacient-ul">
            {{ form.patient.errors }}
            <li><strong>Paciente:</strong>&nbsp {{ form.patient }}  </li>            
       </ul>
    </div>      
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <ul class="pacient-ul">
            <li><strong>Terapeuta:</strong>&nbsp {{ form.therapist }}</li>
            <li><strong>Médico:</strong>&nbsp {{ form.medical }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
.
.
And so sucessively more divs and fields
```

Pero esto hace que yo pierda el efecto o los estilos de bootstrap, debido a que no estoy utilizando la clase `RehabilitationSessionForm` que es en donde se crea el formulario utilizando algunos atributos de `crispy-forms`

El resultado:

Mi formulario esta desplegado sin los efectos css y js de bootstrap-3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo renderizar mi formulario utilizando django-crispy-forms?

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Si yo tengo esto en el template diseño base

```
<div class="box-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 pacient-pic">&nbsp &nbsp<img class="img-circle " src="dist/img/user7-128x128.jpg" alt="User Avatar"></div> 
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                <ul class="pacient-ul">
                    <li><strong>Paciente:</strong>&nbsp Valentina Sepúlveda</li>
                    <li><strong>D.I:</strong>&nbsp 1037548297</li>
                </ul>
            </div>      
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                <h4>Sesión N°</h4>
                <h3 class="padding-left">1</h3>
            </div>  
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                <ul class="pacient-ul">
                  <li><strong>Fecha de inicio:</strong>&nbsp 12/01/1991 - 17:34 hs</li>
                  <li><strong>Terapeuta:</strong>&nbsp Bernardo</li>
                  <li><strong>Médico:</strong>&nbsp Christian</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

¿Cómo podría renderizar estos campos desde el método `__init__` en el `forms.py`?

He intentado esto:

```
class RehabilitationSessionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RehabilitationSessionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        #self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', u'Guardar'))
        self.helper.layout=Layout(
            Div(
                FormActions(
                    Submit('save', 'Save changes'),
                    css_class='box-body btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right fa fa-pencil',

                ),
                Div('patient', css_class='col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-6'),
                Div('therapist', css_class='col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6'),
                Div('medical', css_class='col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6'),
                css_class='row',

            )
        )
```

Y en mi template real a donde llegan los datos o en donde pinto el formulario con `{% crispy form %}`, esta asi

```
{% crispy form %}
<div class="box-body">                
    #<!--<div class="row">-->
    <div class="col-md-2 pacient-pic">&nbsp &nbsp<img class="img-circle " src="{{ sessionedit.patient.user.photo.url }}" alt="User Avatar">
    </div> 
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    #<!--<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">-->
           <ul class="pacient-ul">
               {{ form.patient.errors }}
               <li><strong>Paciente:</strong>&nbsp </li>
               <li><strong>D.I:</strong>&nbsp {{ sessionedit.patient.identity_document }}</li>
           </ul>
    #<!--</div>-->
   <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
       <h4>Sesión N°</h4>
       <h3 class="padding-left">{{ sessionedit.id }}</h3>
   </div>  
   #<!--<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6"> -->
           <ul class="pacient-ul">
              <li><strong>Fecha de inicio:</strong>&nbsp </li>
              <li><strong>Terapeuta:</strong>&nbsp </li>
              <li><strong>Médico:</strong>&nbsp </li>
           </ul>
   #<!-- </div> -->
   #<!--    </div> end row -->
</div>#<!-- /.box-body -->
```

En general segui renderizando, pero no logro ubicar bien mis css's en los divs para los campos. Por ahora mi formulario va quedando asi, [en este url](https://nrhb.herokuapp.com/sesiones-de-rehabilitacion/nuevo/) se puede ver que estan desorganizados los campos, pero con la respuesta dada por [@German-Alzate-Martinez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15252/german-alzate-martinez) ya estoy renderizando los campos de mi formulario utilizando `django-crispy-forms` y enviandolos desde el método `__init__` en mi `forms.py`.

Solo que no he dado con la interpretacion de como renderizar cada cosa.

Cualquier ayuda lo agradezco

Comment: ¿Por qué el título en inglés?

Comment: @Mariano se me fue, ya lo puse en español. Excusas. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la documentación de Django-crispy-forms te dice que puedes ayudarte para renderizar tus campos de formulario desde el **init** de tu formulario, de la siguiente forma:

```
...
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Submit, Div, Field
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import FormActions, StrictButton

class RehabilitationSessionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(RehabilitationSessionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.add_layout = Layout(
            Div(
                Div('patient', css_class='col-md-4'),
                Div('therapist', css_class='col-md-4'),
                Div('medical', css_class='col-md-4'),
                Div(
                    StrictButton('Submit', css_class='btn btn-primary', type='submit'),
                    css_class='col-md-2'
                )
                css_class='row'
            )
        )     
...
```

cabe aclarar que este es un ejemplo demostrativo, ya las clases de css tu las acomodas como te gusta mas para que todo encaje, tambien podrias omitir el ultimo div de el strictbutton, y añadir un `FormActions(Submit('aceptar', 'Aceptar'))`, luego en tu template, solo tienes que llamar asi...

```
...
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<!--Ubicas tu formulario, dentro de cualquier contenedor de acuerdo a tu diseño-->
{% crispy form %} {% comment %}Solo llamas el formulario asi, y el renderiza con los divs y las clases que usaste {% endcomment %}
...
```

Espero haberte ayudado, cualquier pregunta, no dudes en comentar

Comment: Con tu respuesta pude renderizar los campos desde el `forms.py` en el `__init__`, solo que no tengo claro como poner las css's en los divs y que mas helpers utilizar. He escrito **una actualización** por si de pronto tienes oportunidad de verla porfa, te agradezco

Comment: @bgarcial los css en los divs los pones en el atributo `css_class` de cada Div (Objeto de CrispyForms), debes tener en cuenta, que asi como organices los divs en tu metodo __init__, asi se organizarán en el template, tambien acuerdate, que ya esto no es tanto una pregunta de Django si no de css y bootstrap, un consejo seria meter todo el formulario dentro de un contenedor, e ir separando por divs con clase 'row' cada que las clases col-md- sumen 12

Comment: ¿Cada que las clases col-md- sumen 12? es decir `col-md-1-2-3` y asi sucesivamente? No entiendo esta parte

Comment: lo ideal es que dentro de un `div` con clase `row` no superen 12 columnas, porque todo se desborda, es decir, no puedes tener mas de 3 `div` con clase `col-md-4` porque cada uno de esos son 4 columnas, **4 x 3 = 12**, si agregas otro `div` con clase asi sea `col-md-1` ya serian 13, lo cual hace que se desborden...